# Typescript: object.hasOwnProperty() shows true on inherited property. Why?

Tags: typescript, inheritance, hasownproperty

If I understand correctly, `object.hasOwnProperty()` should return false on inherited properties of the parent class. However, the following code returns true on both own and inherited properties.

Is my understanding/code incorrect or is `hasOwnPropery()` incorrect?
If it's me, how do I discriminate between own and inherited properties?

**Edit**: I've added my use case to the sample code.

I would expect the child's `fromDb()` would only take care of its own properties, instead, it overrides the properties set by the parent's `fromDb()`.

```
class Parent {
    parentProp = '';
    fromDb(row: {}) {
        for (const key of Object.keys(row)) {
            if (this.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                if (key === 'parentProp') {
                    // Do some required data cleansing
                    this[key] = row[key].toUpperCase()
                } else {
                    this[key] = row[key];
                }
            }
        };
        return this;
    }
}

class Child extends Parent {
    childProp = '';
    fromDb(row: {}) {
        super.fromDb(row);
        for (const key of Object.keys(row)) {
            if (this.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                this[key] = row[key];
            }
        };
        return this;
    }
}

let row = {
    parentProp: 'parent',
    childProp: 'child',
}

let childObj = new Child().fromDb(row);
console.log(childObj);
```

Console:

```
Child:
    childProp: "child"
    parentProp: "parent"
```

Comment: I wish the MDN page for hasOwnProperty had a little note about typescript `extends`. I think a lot people will just look at the short description on MDN "`The hasOwnProperty() method returns a boolean indicating whether the object has the specified property as its own property (as opposed to inheriting it).`" and draw the wrong conclusion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the generated `extends` code, properties are copied to the subclass like this:

```
function (d, b) { for (var p in b) if (b.hasOwnProperty(p)) d[p] = b[p]; };
```

Which means that your subclass (`d`) is given it's own property.

This is actually no different to using plain JavaScript inheritance:

```
function Parent() {
    this.parentProp = `I'm defined by Parent`;
}

function Child() {
  Parent.call(this);
  this.childProp = `I'm defined by Child`;
}

let childObj = new Child();

for (const key of Object.keys(childObj)) {
    console.log(key, childObj.hasOwnProperty(key));
}
```

If you give us some direction on what you need to achieve, I'm sure we'll find a suitable mechanism for you that will overcome this obstacle.

## Specific Use Case

For your specific use case, you can set the precedent for who "wins" by where you call the superclass.

To get the output

```
childProp: "child"
parentProp: "PARENT"
```

Let the parent run "second", rather than "first":

```
class Child extends Parent {
    childProp = '';
    fromDb(row: {}) {
        for (const key of Object.keys(row)) {
            if (this.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                this[key] = row[key];
            }
        };

        super.fromDb(row); // <-- last update wins
        return this;
    }
}
```

## Super Dynamic Property Stuff

This will dynamically exclude parent keys from the child and child keys from the parent... add `console.log` statements to see the internals...

```
class Parent {
    parentProp = '';
    fromDb(row: {}) {

        const ownKeys = Object.keys(new Parent());

        for (const key of Object.keys(row)) {
            if (ownKeys.indexOf(key) > -1) {
                if (key === 'parentProp') {
                    // Do some required data cleansing
                    this[key] = row[key].toUpperCase()
                } else {
                    this[key] = row[key];
                }
            }
        };
        return this;
    }
}

class Child extends Parent {
    childProp = '';
    fromDb(row: {}) {
        super.fromDb(row);

        const ownKeys = this.getKeys();

        for (const key of Object.keys(row)) {
            if (ownKeys.indexOf(key) > -1) {
                this[key] = row[key];
            }
        };
        return this;
    }

    getKeys() {
        const childKeys = Object.keys(this);
        const parentKeys = Object.keys(new Parent());

        return childKeys.filter( function( el ) {
             return parentKeys.indexOf( el ) < 0;
        });
    }
}

let row = {
    parentProp: 'parent',
    childProp: 'child',
}

let childObj = new Child().fromDb(row);
console.log(childObj);
```

Comment: I have added some details for that specific use case. If you need to be more selective you would have to create a property map so the child would look the map, rather than it's own keys (i.e. "if the property is in my map, I will change it, otherwise I won't").

Comment: It seems the copying happens in both directions. When I add `console.log(Object.keys(this))` to the Parent's `fromDb()`, it also show the properties of the Child when called by `super.fromDb(row)`. I never realized this effect of syntactic sugar. Naive me...

Comment: Yes - because you're dealing with the same JavaScript object in both cases. The map solution seems like the right way to handle things in your case.

Comment: Just tried something similar in Python and the Parent's dictionary did list the Child's properties when called through `super()`. The cleanness of OO I had in mind is a bit shaken right now...

Comment: @passerby super dynamic map example added. Only the child keys are changed by the child. Only the parent keys are changed by the parent.

Comment: Thanks Fenton! I wouldn't have come up with that... Great solution!

Answer (score 1):

Classes are just syntactic sugar for the good old constructor function syntax. Properties defined in the class are always instance properties compiled to values set in the constructor function:

```
function Parent() {
    this.parentProp = "I'm defined by Parent";
}
```

The property does not come from the prototype, it's an instance property set on `this` in the constructor. Only methods are shared on the prototype. If you want shared properties, they must be declared `static`; but then they're a class property and not on the prototype either.